# AzureStorage specific folder in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage

I am using ASP.NET for my project and I need to count the total files within a specific folder on the BlobStorage (Azure).

I am trying to count all the files in this folder: `container_one/year/month/day/hour`

**What I have tried so far:**

```cs
string path = "container_one/year/month/day/hour";
int totalItems = 0;

BlobContainerClient blobFolder = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString).GetBlobContainerClient(path);

foreach(var blob in blobFolder){
   totalItems++;
} 

Console.WriteLine(totalItems);
```

**Resulted in:**

```cs
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
```

What am I doing wrong ? And how could I do it ? I am sure that the provided path does exist on the server.

----EDIT-------

I made the mistake that I did not await the bloblFolder to be loaded. The issue is solved by adding the `await` keyword before `new BlobServiceClient`

So the final code would be :

```cs
string path = "container_one/year/month/day/hour";
int totalItems = 0;

BlobContainerClient blobFolder = await new BlobServiceClient(connectionString).GetBlobContainerClient(path);

foreach(var blob in blobFolder){
   totalItems++;
} 

Console.WriteLine(totalItems);
```

Comment: What is the actual type of `blob`? (This is why I am not a fan of using C#'s `var` for locals).

Comment: Without much other info, I'd say the URI you're providing does not represent any resource on the server. What makes you think the error message isn't correct?

Comment: in this context var would be an Azure.BlobItem

Comment: @mason I ensured that the path I provided does exist on the server's side.

Comment: Are you sure? What is the path on the server side? What is the path you're requesting that fails? Is it always the same path that fails? Could this perhaps be some sort of formatting issue, such as treating January as 01 instead of 1?

Comment: I am 100% sure that the provided path is correct. I think it has more to do with indexing inside this container.

Comment: @schweppes0x What do you see in Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: The issue has been resolved, i did not await the blobfolder and simply ran it async. Awaiting the folder to be loaded fixed my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The working approach I found:**

```cs
int totalCount = 0;
string path = $"{container_one}/{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/";

var blobFolders = _blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
      await foreach (var file in blobFolders)
      {
          if (file.Name.Contains(path))
          {
              totalCount++;
          }
      }
return totalCount;
```

**Remarks**

Doing it this way costs a lot of performance, but I don't see any other options. If anyone has found a solution, please share it with me!

Comment: "Doing it this way costs a lot of performance" - look at the options for making parallel and batched requests in `GetBlobsAsync`. Also, you can greatly improve performance by running your code on an Azure VM compared to running it outside Microsoft's Azure network (e.g. at home or office). I have a LinqPad script that can iterate through a 2 million blobs in 4 minutes when run on an Azure VM, but would take ~2 hours when run from home (and I've got a 1Gbps connection here).

Answer (score 1):

To [expand on the OP's self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69764548/159145) and respond to their request for how to improve performance, I'll share some code from a Linqpad file of mine that can iterate through blobs in Azure Blob Storage at a rate I last recorded as 6.7 million blobs in 6m38s (or about 1 million blobs per minute, or 16,666 blobs *per second*).

Getting blazing blob-iteration speeds like that is doable, but in my case was possible due to 2 things:

- I'm using the Content-Addressable-Storage practice, whereby each blob is immutable and the blob's name is the base-16 representation of its SHA-256 hash.

  - So the statistical distribution of all blob-names is evenly shared into the 16 base16 character "bins" `'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'`.
- The other catch was that because iterating blobs is somewhat *chatty* it means that network-latency between your computer and Blob Storage will drastically slow things down regardless of your internet connection's throughput speed (so using a 100mbps connection with a 1ms latency is far far far more preferable to using a 1Gbps connection with a 100ms latency to your Azure storage account).

  - The workaround is easy though: just spin-up a VM in Azure (you'll only need to rent a VM for an hour or so, so you can safely configure a beefy machine that might cost $1000/mo but will only cost you less than $5 because you only need it for a tiny fraction of a full calendar month).

---

As I mentioned, the fact that my blob-names are evenly (and randomly) distributed through a large number of "prefix bins" is central to why it's able to iterate over them so fast, however provided you can partition your blob-names into evenly-sized bins based on their prefix (including the container name and virtual-path) then it should run just as fast.

---

- Copy and paste the below code into a Linqpad script.
- You'll need to add a NuGet reference to `Azure.Storage.Blobs` (it was written against `12.8.4`, you'll probably need to update and address any breaking changes).
- This script writes all blob URIs (and their Azure-generated MD5 hash) to a binary file for consumption by other processes.

```
static readonly DirectoryInfo _outputDirectory = new DirectoryInfo( Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop ),
    "BlobsDump"
) );

async Task Main() {
    
    _outputDirectory.Create();
    
    // Indexes 8,730,343 blobs in 6m38 seconds (impressive - compared to the few hours it took earlier)
    // UPDATE: Using 2-character prefixes brings total time down to 1m54s to enumerate 9m blobs, wow!
    
    BlobContainerClient cc = CreateBlobClient();
    
    await ListBlobsAsync( cc );
}

private static BlobContainerClient CreateBlobClient()
{
    const String cs = @"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mindyourownbusiness;AccountKey=werenostrangerstoloveyouknowtherulesandsodoiafullcommitmentswhatimthinkingofyouwouldntgetthisfromanyotherguy;BlobEndpoint=https://.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://.table.core.windows.net/;";
    BlobServiceClient c = new BlobServiceClient(cs);
    BlobContainerClient cc = c.GetBlobContainerClient("container-name");
    return cc;
}

private static readonly Char[] _hexDigits = new[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

private static readonly IReadOnlyList<String> _blobNamePrefixes = _hexDigits.SelectMany( hd0 => _hexDigits.Select( hd1 => hd0.ToString() + hd1.ToString() ) ).ToList();

private static async Task ListBlobsAsync( BlobContainerClient cc )
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<String,HashSet<String>> blobNamesPerPrefix = new ConcurrentDictionary<String,HashSet<String>>();
    
    foreach( String prefix in _blobNamePrefixes )
    {
        blobNamesPerPrefix[prefix] = new HashSet<String>(); 
    }
    
    //
    
    Task reportProgressTask = ReportProgressAsync( blobNamesPerPrefix );
    
    List<Task> tasks = _blobNamePrefixes.Select( prefix => ListBlobsAsync( cc: cc, prefix: prefix, dict: blobNamesPerPrefix ) ).ToList();
    
    await Task.WhenAll( tasks ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    Int32 total = blobNamesPerPrefix.Values.Sum( s => s.Count );
}

const Double _lastKnownBlobCountApprox = 8925524; // As of 2020-09-07.

private static async Task ReportProgressAsync( ConcurrentDictionary<String,HashSet<String>> countsSoFar, CancellationToken ct = default )
{
    var pb = new Util.ProgressBar( "Blobs indexed" );
    pb.Dump();
    
    while( true )
    {
        Int32 total = countsSoFar.Values.Sum( v => v.Count );
        pb.Fraction = (Double)total / _lastKnownBlobCountApprox;
        pb.Caption = ( $"{total:N0} blobs observed." );
        
        await Task.Delay( 250 );
    }
}

private static readonly UTF8Encoding _utf8NoBom = new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true ); 

private static async Task ListBlobsAsync( BlobContainerClient cc, String prefix, ConcurrentDictionary<String,HashSet<String>> dict )
{
    HashSet<String> blobs = dict[prefix];
    
    const Int32 ONE_MEGABYTE = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    String outputFileName = Path.Combine( _outputDirectory.FullName, prefix + ".dat" );
    
    using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( outputFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: ONE_MEGABYTE, options: FileOptions.SequentialScan | FileOptions.Asynchronous ) )
    using( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( capacity: ONE_MEGABYTE ) )
    using( BinaryWriter wtr = new BinaryWriter( ms, _utf8NoBom ) )
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        
        await ListBlobsInnerAsync( cc, prefix, blobs, wtr, fs, ms ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        ( $"Completed list with prefix \"{prefix}\". Blob count: {blobs.Count:N0}. Took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds:N0}ms." ).Dump();
    }
}

private static async Task ListBlobsInnerAsync( BlobContainerClient cc, String prefix, HashSet<String> blobs, BinaryWriter wtr, FileStream fs, MemoryStream ms )
{
    Int32 i = 0;
    
    String? continationToken = null;
    do
    {
        System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<Azure.Page<BlobItem>> segment = cc.GetBlobsAsync( prefix: prefix ).AsPages( continationToken );
        await foreach( Azure.Page<BlobItem>? page in segment.ConfigureAwait(false) )
        {
            continationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
            
            if( page.Values.Last().Name[0] > prefix[0] ) break;
            
            lock( blobs )
            {
                foreach( BlobItem bi in page.Values )
                {
                    if( blobs.Add( bi.Name ) )
                    {
                        WriteBlobLine( ref i, bi, wtr );
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Flush:
            wtr.Flush();
            ms.Flush();
            
            ms.Position = 0;
            await ms.CopyToAsync( fs ).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await fs.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.SetLength( 0 );
            wtr.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
        }
    }
    while( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( continationToken ) );
}

private static void WriteBlobLine( ref Int32 i, BlobItem bi, BinaryWriter wtr )
{
    wtr.Write( i );
    wtr.Write( bi.Name ); // Length-prefixed string.
    
    if( bi.Properties.ContentHash != null && bi.Properties.ContentHash.Length == 16 )
    {
        wtr.Write( bi.Properties.ContentHash.Length );
        wtr.Write( bi.Properties.ContentHash );
    }
    else
    {
        wtr.Write( 0 );
    }
    
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The method `.GetBlobContainerClient()` has many overloads, the one which you are trying to call requires to pass in a `Uri` so what you should be doing is `.GetBlobContainerClient(new Uri(path))`.

Comment: This is not the issue the OP is having (if it was, there would be a compile-time error, not a runtime exception). You _can_ pass a `string` value and the Azure library will convert it to a fully-qualified URI for you using the base-URI in the connection-string.